# Python if statement using CSV Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am reading in some data from a CSV file and then printing a value based on an if statement, but it doesn't seem to make sense to me. I would expect it would print `equal to 1`

PYTHON CODE:

```
import csv

#open CSV file
csvfile = open("C:\\python.csv", "rb")
data = csv.reader(csvfile)
data = [row for row in data]

#start loop through each item
for currentrow in range(1, 2):  # numbers off due to array starting at 0
    #grab one record data [row][col]
    Count = data[currentrow][7]

    print "Count equals: " + Count

    if Count > 1:
        print "greater than 1"
    if Count == 1:
        print 'equal to 1'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Count equals: 1.00
greater than 1
```

Comment: Try `Count = int(float(data[currentrow][7]))` inside your for loop

Comment: @inspectorG4dget you should probably post it as an answer. Looks logical.

Comment: Aside: if you're a beginner, I'd strongly recommend using Python 3.  Not only does it have lots of improvements across the board, but you would have seen a very useful error message.

Comment: @alecxe: Checking to make sure that's really what OP wants. There's also the issue of `range(1,2)` that I don't fully understand. So it's hard to tell if what I suggested really fixes the problem in the general case

Comment: @inspectorG4dget this worked great, but now the line `print "Count equals: " + Count` doesn't work because it's combining a number and a string. Do I need to convert back to a string to print and if so how?

Comment: @user2242044: hold on a minute. I'll post make a full post as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trouble stems from the fact that what you read from a file is always a string (i.e. `str` type). This means that even if the file contains a number, it is read into your variable as a string. Therefore, if your file looks like this:

**myFile.txt**:

```
2
```

And if you did:

```
with open('myFile.txt') as infile:
    x = infile.readline()
```

then, `x` would have the value `'2'`, which is a `str` type. This means, that if you did `x*2`, you'd get `'22'`, because that's how strings multiply out.

What you really want, is to convert that sting into an `int`. This is called "casting a string into an integer" and can be done very simply:

```
y = int(x)
```

There's another type that you should be aware of: `float`. It is used to hold decimal numbers. So, if you were to say

```
x = 3.4
```

then `x` would be a `float`. You can also cast `int`s to `float`s:

```
z = float(y)
```

would turn `z` into a float, with the value `2.0`

Now, onto your actual problem:

```
data = [row for row in data]  # data is now a list of lists; each sublist is a list of strings
for currentrow in range(1,2):
    Count = data[currentrow][7]  # Count is now the string at index 7, of the sublist at index `currentrow`, i.e. 1.00
    Count = float(Count)  # Count is now the floating point value of the string '1.00'
    Count = int(Count)  # Count is now the integer value of 1.00, i.e. 1
    if Count > 1:
        print "greater than 1"
    if Count == 1:
        print "equal to 1"
```

Now, onto your second problem:

```
print 'Count equals ' + Count
```

Here, you are trying to add a `str` and an `int`. Well, those are incompatible types for addition. Therefore, you should cast the `int` into a `str`; and just like how `str`s can be cast into `int`s, `int`s can be cast into `str`s with a call to `str()`:

```
Count_str = str(Count)
```

So when  you want to print the value, you could do:

```
print "Count equals " + str(Count)
```

Of course, the print statement is a little more friendly and lets you do something like this:

```
print "Count equals", Count  # no casting needed here
```